# how to get slot according to my location from polyline on map

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, location, google-polyline

I am working on turn to turn navigation. I have successfully draw a route between two points. Now i want to show the current slot information on UI. but i am unable to find the current slot of google api response according to my current location.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use steps data to show the instructions to the user on the UI. You can also use Html_instructions for audio with Text to Speech.This can be handled in onLocationChanged().

Comment: How do we get the Steps data?